# Javascript Convert String to Byte Array using ISO-8859-1 encoding

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

Using Javascript, how can we convert a string to a byte array (byte representation using ISO-8859-1 encoding?

**My Attempt:**

```
function string2byte(str) {
    let byteArray = []
    for (let j=0; j < str.length; j++) {
        byteArray.push(str.charCodeAt(j));
    }

    return byteArray
}

let input = 'helloWorld';
console.log(string2byte(input));
```

gives the output

```
[
    104, 101, 108, 108,
    111,  87, 111, 114,
    108, 100
]
```

Since Javascript strings uses UTF-16 representation, I am guessing the above code is wrong?

*(Not knowing Java)* I believe we need a Javascript version of Java's

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

Thank you for any help!!

---

**Additional details:** I'm actually trying to follow instructions for using an API:

Input is a byte array composed of ordered fields using zero byte (0x00) as a separator. There is no separator before the first field or after the last field. Some fields are always empty in which case the separators immediately follow one another. If converting HTTP header values, and url parts from string to byte representation you should use ISO-8859-1 encoding. For request body you should use the raw bytes as they are sent to the server. For JSON messages the character encoding should always be UTF-8.

Input structure is the following:

- API Key (eg: 4ebd366d-76f4-4400-a3b6-e51515d054d6)
- X-Time request header value (eg: 1543597115712)

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks, updated code with `let byteArray = []`

Comment: `charCodeAt` gives the ASCII character code. What were you actually expecting as output?

Comment: Also, checking the table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), it looks like the alphabet is fine - but where did those extra characters come from? `helloWorld` is only 10 characters, thus there should be 10 codes.

Comment: @JackBashford From my best understanding, the output should by a byte array, where an example of an element can be a zero byte `0x00`.

Comment: NodeJS has [`Buffer.from()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding) function which takes the target encoding as parameter.

Comment: @JackBashford Updated question with the correct result